# SlidingTabLayout pressed tab background color

Tags: android, tabs

Using SlidingTabLayout from https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

It works fine but I would like to replace the default color of a tab when it's in pressed state. How can this be done?